# datatable example not working to fixed column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to implement datatable fixed colum example coping from there side inside my code but it simply dopesn't work. I created a jsfiddle with the same code but columns are not fixed.

site:
https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/two_columns.html

JS sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/jsf6cg6L/229/

```
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 1,
            rightColumns: 1
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 2):

Your fiddle is missing a dependency:

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js
```

Adding it as an external resource makes it work.